# Show Eclipse mini progress bar?

Tags: eclipse

Silly question: How do I get the tiny progress bar back in Eclipse ? I managed to drag it out of existance...

[image]

Comment: I am also facing same issue and the answers posted here did not help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you remove only progress bar.
I guess you removed console window. 
To add console window go to
 **Window --> Show View --> console**

Comment: I tried showing and hiding the console view, but this did not affect the visibility of the progress bar in the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

Maximize eclipse window and it will pop back up. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring Down and Maximizing the Eclipse window also did the trick for me.

Comment: Working for me too